# Java Iterator not working as expected

Tags: java

I am trying to use an iterator to add a Service object to and ArrayList called ShuttleTimetable only if the service dosnt already exist within the Timetable. Yet as seen by the ouput the iterator in the add method stays the same even when the timetable changes. I am a beginner and do not understand why. I would love an insight into why this is.

```
public void addService(Service service) throws NullPointerException {
        boolean contains=false;
        if (service==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        Iterator<Service> itr = ShuttleTimetable.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            Service s=itr.next();
            System.out.println(s.toString()); //this is just to test the iterator
            if (service.equals(s))
                contains=true;
                break;
        }
        if (contains==false)
            ShuttleTimetable.add(service);
        }
```

The following code is what i am using to test the functionality:

```
public class ogshuttltest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Venue[] venues =
            { new Venue("House of Noise"), new Venue("arena"),
                    new Venue("The Corner"), new Venue("hell") };

    int[] sessions = { 1, 2, 5 };
    Service[] services =
            { new Service(venues[0], venues[1], sessions[0]),
                    new Service(venues[0], venues[2], sessions[0]),
                    new Service(venues[0], venues[1], sessions[1]),
                    new Service(venues[2], venues[3], sessions[0]),
                    new Service(venues[1], venues[3], sessions[1]),
                    new Service(venues[1], venues[0], sessions[1]),
                    new Service(venues[1], venues[3], sessions[1]) };
    ShuttleTimetable timetable = new ShuttleTimetable();
    for (Service s: services)
        timetable.addService(s);
    System.out.println(timetable);

}
}
```

This is the resulting output:

```
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena
Departs House of Noise after session 1 for arena, Departs House of Noise after session 1 for The Corner, Departs House of Noise after session 2 for arena, Departs The Corner after session 1 for hell, Departs arena after session 2 for hell, Departs arena after session 2 for House of Noise, Departs arena after session 2 for hell,
```

Comment: can you provide code for shuffletimetable and Service

Comment: And tell us why you don't simply use the contains() method of the backing collection instead of using an iterator?

Comment: i feel very silly now, yes i should probably just use the contains method(). thanks

Comment: Dit you override the `equals()` method in class `Service`? It will not work correctly if you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

As @JB Nizet say, using contains will save you a lot of work. However, It is important to understand what is happening in your code.

First of all, your print-statement does not print the iterator, but the current iterator item. Which is a service in your case.

Second, you might not have provided custom implementation of the equals(..) method in Service. The default implementation of the equals method compares object references. I suppose, in your example, the services are equal whenever their venues and sessions match, not when their object references match. Therefore if you haven't overridden the equals-method, it might "act strangely".

Btw. whenever you override "equals", you should also override the hashCode method to prevent inconsistencies. This is especially important, if you are going to use the "contains" method from ArrayList.

Comment: The hashCode() method plays no role in ArrayList.contains(). It plays a role when storing instances of Service in a HashSet, or as a key in a HashMap.